# Download all pom files from maven repository

Tags: java, maven, web-scraping

I am looking for a way to download all pom files from the maven central repository. I do not need the jars, just the pom files. Now I could scrape the website, but I am sure the guys at maven.org would not appreciate it. Is there any other way?

Comment: Why would you like to do that? What would you like to achieve?

Comment: @khmarbaise Think of it as an R&D activity. I am trying to find out, for example, the most popular projects, or most used dependencies etc among other things.

Comment: This can be done via Maven Central itself which has download statistics. You don't need to download them yourself which will not solve your problem. I would suggest to ask sonatype. The dependency between project will not result in the most used dependencies.

Comment: Central would eventually block you, when trying to download all poms (see https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html, last pagagraph)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to scrape the whole web site? Why dont you just use the maven dependency plugin to resolve just the dependencies related to your project?

Comment: Think of it as an R&D activity. The pom files contain interesting information about the project, the authors, the scm repos etc. I am trying to find out, for example, the most popular projects, or most used dependencies etc. It is not for resolving dependencies.

Comment: You should still explain WHY you want that kind of information if you want people to drop the sensation you're a novice that doesn't really think it through. I can't think if a single reason why you would want to know which dependencies are popular, unless you want that information to know which dependencies to use yourself. Which is -horrible- logic.

Comment: @Gimby Lets just say I want to build a catalog of projects, opensource and otherwise. Similar to say ohloh.net but for an entirely different purpose. Maven repo seemed like a good source to seed such a catalog. Number of times a project appears as a dependency can be imho one factor in determining the overall ranking of a project? No?